Import model in angular
I have an error importing a model into another model, all files are in the same folder
[Problem in api-response]
(https://i.sstatic.net/cWzaYIxg.png)
export class Drink {
  idDrink!: string;
  strDrink!: string;
  strCategory!: string;
  strAlcoholic!: string;
  strGlass!: string;
  strInstructionsES!: string;
  strDrinkThumb!: string;
  strIngredient1!: string;
  strIngredient2!: string;
  strIngredient3!: string;
  strIngredient4!: string;
  strIngredient5!: string;
  strIngredient6!: string;
  }

import { Drink } from './drink';

export interface Response {
  data: Drink[];
}

import { Drink } from './drink';

export class DrinkResponse {
  data!: Drink[];
}

import { Drink } from './drink';
import { DrinkResponse } from './drinkResponse';

export class ApiResponse implements DrinkResponse {
  data: Drink[];

  constructor() {
    this.data = [{
        idDrink:"string",
        strDrink:"string",
        strCategory:"string",
        strAlcoholic:"string", 
        strGlass:"string",
        strInstructionsES:"string",
        strDrinkThumb:"string",
        strIngredient1:"string",
        strIngredient2:"string",
        strIngredient3: "string",
        strIngredient4:"string",
        strIngredient5:"string",
        strIngredient6:"string"
    }];
  }
}

I've tried everything I can think of, but I can't seem to find the error. It seems like everything is correct to me, but to be honest, I'm new to Angular, so if you could help me, I would really appreciate it. I imagine the error must be something simple. Greetings.

If the other answer doesnt solve it, you should verify that the extension of all the files are .ts

Many thanks! That solved my problem, you are the best programmer in the world :)

DrinkResponse is a class not an interface. It must be extends not implement.
Just fix export class ApiResponse implements DrinkResponse to export class ApiResponse extends DrinkResponse and error go out.

I tried with that but the problem was not solved.

remove data: Drink[]; from ApiResponse. Parent class already has it.

The same, I tried with that but the problem was not solved
